# Update managed metadata Multi Value

Tags: powershell, managed-metadata, updatelistitems, managed-metadata-service

I have a list which uses a managed metadata column, that is configured to have multiple values.

I need to update the particular items in the list which have a specific term, and change it.

For example, Column1 contains {apple, pear, banana}

I need to remove 'apple' and add 'car' so that Column1 now becomes {car, pear, banana} (order does not matter)

So far I have retrieved the column, and its collection using the code below:

```
$camlQuery = "<Where>
            <Eq>
                <FieldRef Name='Column1' />
                    <Value Type='Text'>apple</Value>
            </Eq>
          </Where>"

$web = Get-SPWeb http://my
$list = $web.Lists['myList']
$spQuery = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQuery
$spQuery.Query = $camlQuery
$spListItems = $list.GetItems($spQuery)

foreach ($item in $spListItems)
{
  $spItem = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem]$item
  $file = $item.File

  if($item.Fields.ContainsField("Column"))
  {
    $file.CheckOut()
    $taxField = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.TaxonomyField]$item.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName("Column")

    $taxFieldCollection = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.TaxonomyFieldValueCollection]$item[$taxField.Title]

    if($taxField.AllowMultipleValues) 
    {
        foreach ($field in $taxFieldCollection)
        {
        }
    }
    $file.Update()
    $file.CheckIn("checked-in", [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPCheckinType]::MajorCheckIn)
  }
}
```

I have also connected to the metadata service, and retrieved the term that I am required to add to the metadata column using:

```
$centralAdmin = Get-SPWebApplication -IncludeCentralAdministration | Where {$_.IsAdministrationWebApplication} | Get-SPSite  
$session = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession($centralAdmin)  
$serviceApp = Get-SPServiceApplication | Where {$_.DisplayName -eq "Managed Metadata Service"}  
$termStore = $session.TermStores[$serviceApp.Name]  
$termSet = $termStore.Groups["Group"].TermSets["TermSet"].Terms["Terms"]

$terms = $termSet.GetTerms()
$term = $terms | ?{$_.Name -eq $value} #$value is 'car'

return $term
```

How do I remove the unwanted to term and add the new one? I am a bit stuck at the moment, and are unsure how to proceed.

For reference I have been looking through ([Powershell: Cannot update taxonomy type column item with multiple values](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/84956/powershell-cannot-update-taxonomy-type-column-item-with-multiple-values))